# Preciso verificar se o item não existe antes de adicioná-lo no ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
switch (menuCad) {
  case 1:
    do {

      System.out.print("Digite o nome: ");
      String nomeProd = Stringentrada.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Digite o preço: ");
      double precoProd = entrada.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Digite o codigo: ");
      int codProd = entrada.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Digite a unidade: ");
      String undProd = Stringentrada.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Digite a Quantidade: ");
      int qtdProd = entrada.nextInt();
      System.out.println("CONFIRMA INCLUSÃO ( S/N ) ?");
      escolha = entrada.next();
      if (escolha.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
        Produto p = new Produto();
        p.setNomeProd(nomeProd);
        p.setPrecoProd(precoProd);
        p.setCodProd(codProd);
        p.setUndProd(undProd);
        p.setQtdProd(qtdProd);
        produtos.add(p);
        if (!produtos.add(Produto)) {
          System.out.println("Esse produto já foi cadastrado!");
        }
      }
      op = getRepetir();
    } while (op.equalsIgnoreCase("S"));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia formatar o código para melhor exibição? Aqui usamos o markdown.

Comment: puts nem sei kkkv ovu tentar

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde.
Essa validação você tem que fazer no método que adiciona o objeto na lista.

```
    //Adicionar um objeto na lista
  static public void adicionar(ProdutoModel produto) {
    if (listaProdutos.contains(produto)) {
     System.out.println("PRODUTO JÁ CADASTRADO!");
    } else {
      listaProdutos.add(produto);
      System.out.println("PRODUTO CADASTRADO!");
    }
  }
```

Em vez de ser produtos.**add** é produtos.**contains** e tem que ser direto na lista.
Espero ter ajudado.